# Why do asymmetric stretches occur at higher wavenumbers than symmetric stretches?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

I learned that the $\ce{N-H}$ bonds in a primary amine lead to two signals the infrared spectra at $\sim \pu{3400 cm^-1}$, one for symmetrical stretching and another for asymmetrical stretching. For example, here is the IR spectrum of butylamine, taken from Pavia & Lampman's *Introduction to Spectroscopy* (5th ed.):

[image: Butylamine]

The same is seen in, for example, carbon dioxide, where the asymmetric stretch ($\Sigma_\mathrm u^+$) occurs at $\pu{2348 cm-1}$ and the symmetric stretch ($\Sigma_\mathrm g^+$) at $\pu{1373 cm-1}$ (from [ChemTube 3D](http://www.chemtube3d.com/vibrationsCO2.htm); the NIST Webbook gives similar values).

Why is this so?